# Maven check that all dependencies have been released

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, versions-maven-plugin

As part of my release process, I use `mvn versions:use-releases` goal to replace all -SNAPSHOT dependencies with released versions. After this, I want to check if all the SNAPSHOT dependencies have been replaced with releases or not.

**Question**: How can I check it?

I know, the maven release plugin performs such a check as part of `release-prepare` goal, but I don't want to use release plugin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`maven-enforcer-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html) to double check whether any SNAPSHOT dependency is still there or not.

From [the official example](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireReleaseDeps.html) of its `requireReleaseDeps` rule:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-no-snapshots</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireReleaseDeps>
                  <message>No Snapshots Allowed!</message>
                </requireReleaseDeps>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Note the `fail` element set to `true`, in this case the build would fail if any `SNAPSHOT` dependency was found.

You could place such configuration in a [maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and activate it when required (hence whenever this check must be performed).

Comment: You can also run this as a one-off from the command line with `mvn enforcer:enforce -Drules=requireReleaseDeps`

Answer (score 1):

The requireReleaseDeps built-in rule of the maven-enforcer-plugin does not apply for dependencies of plugins. It is a quite rare case, but plugins can carry their own dependencies to augment their default behaviour.

If someone is interested in checking for SNAPSHOT dependencies of plugins, configure the maven-enforcer-plugin in this way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-no-snapshots</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <!-- Add this rule (don't forget the 'implementation' hint! ) -->
                    <requireReleaseDepsInPlugins implementation="org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.requireReleaseDepsInPlugins" />
                </rules>
                <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add this dependency to the plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.thefolle</groupId>
            <artifactId>glowing-waffle</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

[glowing-waffle](https://github.com/Thefolle/glowing-waffle) is a collection of custom rules for the enforcer plugin. It defines the requireReleaseDepsInPlugins rule.