# Check that project version is not a SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven

Quite similar to [Maven check that all dependencies have been released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113721/maven-check-that-all-dependencies-have-been-released), Maven should also automatically check, that the version of the current version is not a SNAPSHOT.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: The current version should be a SNAPSHOT to create a release of it otherwise you already have a release !

Comment: @khmarbaise During the research for this I stumbled over the `maven-release-plugin`. Till now I made these steps manually, e.g. creating a release branch, updating the version etc.
But I am taking a look at the  `maven-release-plugin` atm.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that the `maven-enforcer-plugin` provides a built-in rule for this task.
Nevertheless the `requireProperty` can be configured to perform the check.

I put the following snippet in my `release` profile.
The first execution checks that the project version does not contain the String `SNAPSHOT`.
The second execution checks that no dependency is a `SNAPSHOT` version.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-property</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <requireProperty>
            <property>project.version</property>
            <message>"Project version must be specified."</message>
            <regex>^(?!.*SNAPSHOT).+$</regex>
            <regexMessage>"Project version must not contain -SNAPSHOT."</regexMessage>
          </requireProperty>
        </rules>
        <fail>true</fail>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-no-snapshots</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <requireReleaseDeps>
            <message>No Snapshots Allowed!</message>
          </requireReleaseDeps>
        </rules>
        <fail>true</fail>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```